# Set openpyxl cell format to currency

Tags: python, excel, currency, openpyxl, cell-formatting

I'm creating an excel sheet using openpyxl. Some cells represent monetary values. How can I change the format of a cell to be of type "currency", i.e. I want a "€" symbol to be displayed after the number.

Comment: why not save it as unicode string?

Comment: actually, this was the workaround I'm using at the moment. However, I feel it is cleaner to add the semantic information to the cell, that I could still use it for calculation in excel if needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try [setting the format code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387212/openpyxl-setting-number-format) with your [desired format code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68)

```
_cell.number_format = '#,##0.00€'
```

Comment: your code didn't work for me out of the box, but it guided me to the solution. `_cell.number_format = '#,##0.00€'` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: That was the older API. We changed in recent versions to make it simpler to use.

Comment: @Dominic where exactly is the difference between your code and the accepted answer?

Comment: @Gigino There is no difference. There was a difference before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have any problem using other than 4 currencies mention on [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
you can also put your currencies according to excel

example:

Russian Ruble: `₽ #,##0.00`

Indonesian Rupiah `Rp #,##0.00`

this is based on @absolutelyNoWarranty answer