# Merge two excel files together into one excel file with a sheet for each file while also retaining formatting

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have two excel files. One file is a table of data and the other file is a coversheet containing some dates/descriptive information.

Is there a way, preferably using openpyxl, where I can combine these two files (data and coversheet) into a new excel file (final) with one sheet containing the coversheet and a second sheet containing the data. I need to retain the formatting of the coversheet.

I can copy one file to another row by row

```
import openpyxl as op 
from openpyxl import Workbook

dest_wb = Workbook()

dest_wb.create_sheet("Cover Sheet")
dest_ws = dest_wb["Cover Sheet"]

source_wb = op.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\coversheet.xlsx")
source_sheet = source_wb.active

for row in source_sheet.rows:
    for cell in row:
        dest_ws[cell.coordinate] = cell.value

dest_wb.save(r"C:\Users\test.xlsx")

dest_wb.close()
source_wb.close()
```

But this doesn't retain any of the formatting from the original file

Comment: You're explicitly copying only values when you call `dest_ws[cell.coordinate] = cell.value`

Comment: Looks like you have to do it the hard way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440284/setting-styles-in-openpyxl#8441753

Comment: Openpyxl basically works with cells. Assuming you are able to; It is much, much easier to do this with Xlwings since you are doing the same the move/copy sheets manually in Excel.